# Detect Github PRs in Xcode Cloud

Tags: ios, github, xcode-cloud

I have authorised Xcode Cloud to access a Github repository with several PRs. Then I have create a PR that should trigger on Pull Request changes.

For some reason, when I say "Start Build" in my PR workflow (in Xcode or in App Store Connect), it only shows *some* PRs. Why could that be?

Furthermore, adding new PRs doesn't change this. When I checked Xcode Cloud in AppStore Connect, it shows that my repository was last checked 30 minutes ago.

How to make it all instantaneous, compete and reliable?